# Position parents relative to child

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to keep a div stuck to the left edge of the screen in CSS, by letting parents overflow the screen.
Basically I want to position the child relative to the screen, but not take it out of the flow of its parents, but rather move all of the parents with the child.

My goal is to make a focusable div fill the screen horizontally, as if it were zoomed onto. The parent elements should overflow the screen.
basically I want this effect:

```
Parent
    Child
/Parent
```

```
nt
Child
ent
```

Note how the parents are overflowing the left edge of the screen.

My situation is that I have a CSS grid, and I want to position the entire grid so that a column is right at the left edge of the screen.

How could I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to achieve. At all.

Comment: You could achieve this with a negative `margin-left` if you knew the position of the child, which you could get via javascript using [getBoundingClientReact](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on the child.

Comment: @connexo I don't know what else I should explain about this. See the example. I did update the question, but it did not get reopened and I did not know how long it would take to get reopened, or if at all.

Comment: I think I understand what OP is asking for and have provided a proof-of-concept implementation below. Can this be reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick proof-of-concept implementation using a negative left margin and a bit of javascript.

```js
// adjusts the container's margin to align the focused item
const focusHandler = ({target}) => {
  // get the left position of the focused element.
  const {left} = target.getBoundingClientRect();

  // get the left position of the container.
  const {left: containerLeft} = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  // adjust the container's left margin
  container.style.marginLeft = `${containerLeft - left}px`;
}

// listen for all focusin events on the container
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('focusin', focusHandler);
```

```css
.container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw; /* prevent the container from getting wider as the margin changes */
}

.container div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.container :focus {
  background: bisque;
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div tabindex="0">Item 1</div>
  <div tabindex="0">Item 2</div>
  <div tabindex="0">Item 3</div>
  <div tabindex="0">Item 4</div>
  <div tabindex="0">Item 5</div>
  <div tabindex="0">Item 6</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works somewhat, but this does not move the parents, but only positions the child relative to the parent.

Comment: I now apply the negative margin to the body of the document, this achieves what I need. Thanks for the suggestion.